# Console showing error tinymce is not defined on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, module

I have an issue with Wordpress admin. I can't add a new post or page and the console is showing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined'.

I found out that the function 'script_loader_tag' on my functions.php is causing the error (everything works fine without it) but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

These are the JS functions:

```
    function loadJS() {
      wp_register_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');
      wp_enqueue_script('custom-js');
    }   

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadJS');


    function add_module_to_script($tag, $handle, $src) {
      if('custom-js' !== $handle ) {
      return $src;
    } 
    $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url($src) . '"></script>';
    return $tag;
    }

    add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_module_to_script', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that you do not alter the $tag when the handle is not equal to "custom-js". And you should return $tag, not the $src.

```
function add_module_to_script($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if('custom-js' !== $handle ) {
      return $tag;
    } 

    $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url($src) . '"></script>';

    return $tag;
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_module_to_script', 10, 3);
```

Better yet.

```
function add_module_to_script($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if('custom-js' == $handle ) {
      $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url($src) . '"></script>';
    } 

    return $tag;
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_module_to_script', 10, 3);
```